# How to create my own endpoint in Django with rest_framework_json_api?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django and need some help to understand! I have been able to create the Api and it works! But ... how do I create an endPoint to do something specific that I want? For example, validate an email? In other words, with a views.ModelViewSet how to define for example def validate (request):

I tell you that I have created the endpoint that mentions them but I have to make some arrangements so that the answer is as I expect it.

```
class SomeViewSet(views.ModelViewSet):

    allowed_methods = ('GET', 'PATCH', 'POST', 'OPTIONS')
    queryset = Some.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SomeSerializer


     def validate(request):

        email = request.GET.get("email", None)
        if email and Some.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            return JsonResponse({'message': 'Email already exists.'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return JsonResponse({'message': 'Email does not exist.'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

rest_framework.response.Response does not work here!

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to create an endpoint that behaves the same as the other ModelViewSet methods?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using restframework its better to create the validate method in a class which you can use as a serializer, and the class should be defined in the serializer.py file.

```
class SomeViewSetSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
   class META:
       model = SomeViewSet

   def validate(attrs):
       email = attrs.get("email", None)
       if email and not Some.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise serializer.ValidationError("Email does not exist")
       return attrs
```